# Rails 5.2 - ArgumentError when trying to define enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums, ruby-on-rails-5

My class defines an *enum* with the values `enum source: [:pdf, :zip]`. Everytime I start my Rails app, the following error appears:

```
ArgumentError: You tried to define an enum named "source" on the model "ExtractionRule", 
but this will generate a class method "zip", which is already defined by ActiveRecord::Relation.
```

**Before the update to 5.2.4, there was no problem with this**. Was there any update on ActiveRecord lib that prevents creating an *enum* with a value `:zip`?

There is nothing on the release notes that says otherwise. I've already looked into Rails source code but couldn't find anything that would create this issue.

**Note**: Changing the name of the values to something else like `[:pdf_type, :zip_type]` fixes the issue, but I would rather keep the code as it his since this was working in the past.

**UPDATE**
I've managed to tackle this issue by using `prefix: :source`. This way I could keep the same values for the *enum*. Either way, I don't know why the error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method in question is actually [Enumerable#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html) which a part of the Ruby standard library:

```
irb(main):049:0> ['a','b', 'c'].zip([1,2,3])
=> [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]
```

Which merges arrays together. `ActiveRecord::Relation` includes Enumerable which is what makes it act like an array.

> Before the update to 5.2.4, there was no problem with this. Was there
>   any update on ActiveRecord lib that prevents creating an enum with a
>   value :zip?

Did you have an ancient Ruby version before the update? As said previously this method is a part of Ruby and not AR. And it actually a completely irrelevant question - defining class methods that collide with enumerable is not a good idea as you sooner or later will interact with code that relies on `#zip` actually zipping arrays.

Comment: The ruby version was updated from 2.4.5 to 2.5.5. Oh so `#zip` belongs to `Enumerable`. I noticed that `Enumerable` was included in `ActiveRecord::Relation` but I didn't join the dots. Thank you @max for the clarification